# How do I print the a specific element of an Array of tuples in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have an Array:

```
foo: Array[(Double, Double)] = Array((1.0,0.7549600618397321), (0.0,0.270666939722848))
```

and I want to print 0.7549600618397321 with 3 decimal places, like this:

```
println(f"${foo(0)}%.3f ")
```

but I get this error:

```
error: type mismatch; found   : (Double, Double) required: Double
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not an array, it's a tuple

Comment: `val foo: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 0.4944029850746269)`

Comment: The edit by @mkUltra confuses the situation. Now all the comments, and the opening of the accepted answer, make no sense.

Comment: Sorry: it was an array. My mistake in pasting it in.

Comment: An array of tuples, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is no array, it's a Tuple. One option to print the first element is to access `_1` of the tuple, in your case:

```
println(f"${foo._1}%.3f ")
```

another option is to use pattern matching:

```
val (first, _) = foo
println(f"${first}%.3f ")
```

Comment: add ```println(f"${foo._1}%.3f ")```

Comment: Thanks. Excuse my ignorance but would this work for an Array as well?

Comment: @schoon You mean pattern matching? Yes, you can write something like `val Array(first, _) = foo` when `foo` is an array of two elements. But `_1` and `_2` won't work, it's declared as a `val` for `Tuple2` and has nothing to do with Arrays.

Comment: Errr it does not work (Scala says it IS an array): <console>:184: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Array[(Double, Double)]
       val (first, _) = foo
           ^

Comment: And if I do it tthe other way: error: value _1 is not a member of Array[(Double, Double)]